# Income Tax form in India for freelancing

Tags: income-tax, india

If I have income only through freelancing (developing software for a US based Company) and am not a incorporated business do I need to file ITR4 or ITR2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ITR1 or ITR2 needs to be filed. Declare the income through freelancing in the section "income from other sources"

Comment: Thanks Dheer. I have filed a return with ITR4 and received a communication about defective return asking to fill balance sheet and profit and loss account. Can I still change the form and file a return with ITR1 or ITR2

Answer (score 0):

Since you are living in India and earning income not from salary, you must file your tax return under **ITR4**(Profits or Gains of Business or Profession). You can do it online on IncomeTax India eFiling website, step by step guide available [here](http://www.texient.com/2015/07/india-income-tax-e-filing-for-freelances-bpo-seo-blogger.html).